# Handling FormatExceptions using XmlSerializer.Deserialize

Tags: .net, xmlserializer, formatexception

I have a third party web service that returns this xml

```
<book>
  <release_date>0000-00-00</release_date>
</book>
```

I am trying to deserialize it into this class

```
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement("release_date")]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

But because `0000-00-00` isn't a valid `DateTime`, I get a FormatException. What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the 3rd party schema defines that field as datetime, then it should always contain a valid datetime value unless something goes wrong.
In this case, you may consider to deserialize it as a string

```
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement("release_date")]
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? GetReleaseDate 
    { 
      get 
      {
           // parse ReleaseDate datetime string
           // return the value; or null if the string contains invalid datetime.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: third party isn't .net so not necessarily a DateTime, hence the 0000-00-00. The string approach you suggested is what I also did but it feels hacky and hoped there might be a cleaner solution

Comment: What type of release_date is described in the WSDL? string? or there is no WSDL, in this case, it should be deserialized as string first and then apply your own logic I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Book
{
    [XmlElement("release_date")]
    public string StringReleaseDate
    {
        get {return ReleaseDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");}
        set {ReleaseDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd");}
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Your code example wouldn't improve things. By putting `DateTime.ParseExact()` inside `StringReleaseDate`'s setter you'll still get a FormatException at deserialization time. The answer provided by @ray-lu is better because at deserialization time ReleaseDate does not throw. The exception, if any, would come later when accessing `GetReleaseDate`'s getter. You would avoid the exception altogether by using `DateTime.TryParseExact()` and returning `null` if that fails.

Comment: Why do you think it's a good idea to return null? Better to throw the exception and fix the problem rather than hide the problem.

Comment: I mentioned `DateTime.TryParseExact()` and `null` because @ray-lu's answer declared `GetReleaseDate` as a `Nullable<DateTime>`, implying that `null` is an appropriate getter response. It is almost never appropriate throw an exception while a record is being deserialized by .NET - I prefer to surface the faulty information through a `SoapException` or a side channel (like a GUI or email) so that the responsible party can see the faulty information and why it was rejected. If a `FormatException` occurs inside `XmlReader` then you'll have no data available to report that information.

Comment: SoapException is an Exception.